# Django - How to add multiple objects to a database dyanmically via a API endpoint use rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Django** supports a method to allow you to query your database and add multiple objects to it using the Objects.create_bulk()

I’ve had a good look on google to better understand how to use this method, but i’m not sure how to achieve what it is i’m trying to achieve.

Here’s where i’m at so far:
I’ve created an api endpoint that lists all the inventory objects that currently exists
I’ve also created an api endpoint that allows you to filter by playerId and will return all inventory items that player owns

Here’s what i’m trying to do:
Create an API endpoint that allows multiple elements to be added to a specified users inventory (playerId)

I just need an endpoint to allow a POST method to append multiple elements to a specified player’s inventory, it should look something like this:

```
def add_multiple_items_to_inventory(request, pk):
    itemsToAdd = Inventory.objects.bulk_create(
[Inventory(
playerId: 1, 
elementId: 2, 
elementId: 2, 
elementId: 2, 
elementId: 4, 
elementId: 7))

    serializer = InventorySerializer(data=itemsToAdd)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

so hitting this endpoint with some data like this ->
{
playerId:1,
elementId: 1,
elementId: 1,
elementId: 1,
elementId: 2,
elementId: 2,
elementId: 7,
}
should add elements [1,1,1,2,2,7] to the player with the id of: 1

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_to_inventory(request, pk):
     #tried using Objects.create_bulk(), but unsure sure how to use it for what i'm trying to do
    inventory = Inventory.objects.filter(playerId=pk)
   
    serializer = InventorySerializer(instance=inventory, data=request.data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response('Nope')

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


class Player(models.Model):
    playerId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    credits = models.IntegerField(default=500)
    AP = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    tier = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.playerId)


class Elements(models.Model):
    elementId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    elementTier = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Inventory(models.Model):
    playerId = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    elementId = models.ForeignKey(Elements, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.playerId)
```

Note: I will be using plain javascript ajax calls to hit these endpoints, so if a solution is found, could you also take into consideration that i'd need a way of saying something like add_element(elementId, quantity), so i can just choose what element(s) to add, and how many to add. I'm really sorry this question is quite heavy and could definitely be worded better, I've searched everywhere on the internet for something similar but can only find people using the Object.creat_bulk method where they hard code what data is posted. If there's a better way to achieve what i'm trying to achieve then i'm all ears! Thanks in advance

Comment: ```
{ playerId:1, elementId: 1, elementId: 1, elementId: 1, elementId: 2, elementId: 2, elementId: 7, }

``` is the data looks like this only

Comment: @shivankgtm I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Migrate over to Postgres, in this case using the ArrayField method on my model solved the issue.